# Change grid color in C3.js

Tags: c3.js

[image]

How can I achieve this grid and label colors. I can find some answers on label colors but nothing on changing the grid color to the one shown in the screenshot, instead of the default black one.

Just in case you need my working code:

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#chart',
    data: {
      x: 'x',
      columns: [
        ['x', ...xAxis],
        ['total', ...yAxis],
      ],
      type: 'bar',
      colors: {
        total: d3.rgb(40,162,245)
      },
      empty: { label: { text: "No Data Available" }}
    },
    axis: {
      x: {
        tick: {
          culling: {
            max: 31,
          },
        },
      },
      y: {
        tick: {
          format: (x) => x / 1000 + 'k',
        },
      },
    },
    grid: {
      y: {
        show: true,
        color: '#fff'
      },
    },
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use selector `.c3 path, .c3 line:not([stroke-width="10"])` for lines, and `tspan` for text.

`.c3 line[stroke-width="10"]` is used for legend squares, it needs be excluded.

Also see [How to get rounded corner in c3js bar charts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28069216/how-to-get-rounded-corner-in-c3js-bar-charts)

```js
const  xAxis = [10, 20, 40];
const  yAxis = [2000, 1420, 1000];

var chart = c3.generate({
bindto: '#chart',
data: {
  x: 'x',
  columns: [
    ['x', ...xAxis],
    ['total', ...yAxis],
  ],
  type: 'bar',
  colors: {
    total: d3.rgb(40,162,245)
  },
  empty: { label: { text: "No Data Available" }}
},
axis: {
  x: {
    tick: {
      culling: {
        max: 31,
      },
    },
  },
  y: {
    tick: {
      format: (x) => x / 1000 + 'k',
    },
  },
},
grid: {
  y: {
    show: true,
    color: '#fff'
  },
},
  })
```

```css
.c3 path, .c3 line:not([stroke-width="10"]) {
  stroke: gold !important;
}

tspan {
  stroke: green !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.16.0/d3.min.js" integrity="sha512-FHsFVKQ/T1KWJDGSbrUhTJyS1ph3eRrxI228ND0EGaEp6v4a/vGwPWd3Dtd/+9cI7ccofZvl/wulICEurHN1pg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.7.20/c3.min.js" integrity="sha512-+IpCthlNahOuERYUSnKFjzjdKXIbJ/7Dd6xvUp+7bEw0Jp2dg6tluyxLs+zq9BMzZgrLv8886T4cBSqnKiVgUw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.7.20/c3.min.css" integrity="sha512-cznfNokevSG7QPA5dZepud8taylLdvgr0lDqw/FEZIhluFsSwyvS81CMnRdrNSKwbsmc43LtRd2/WMQV+Z85AQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<div id="chart">
```